# Help with comparator and Hopper (Minecraft Java edition)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here:

Here's my set-up.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My hopper at the back that's supposed to move the 1 item around refuses to do so for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The fact that both redstone torches are on (they are supposed to alternate) says that something isn't right. Did you place everything in the same order as the tutorial does?

Comment: @Ben I think I followed the tutorial, but I guess I'll have to try again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bottom comparators are facing in opposite direction than they should. They are supposed to read the lower hoppers (with the 'two sticks' side, through the block) and power the blocks underneath the torches (with the 'pointy' side).

[image]

Comment: Good catch! Yes, this is what turns the redstone torches on and off, thereby "locking" and "unlocking" the top hoppers alternately.